# Lenovo G500 Bluetooth stopped working

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo G500 laptop. Its OS is Windows 8. When I bought my laptop everything was working fine. But for a week, now Bluetooth is not working. I looked in the 'Device Manager' and Bluetooth was not found there.

Why can't I find Bluetooth there? How can I make my Bluetooth work again?

---

UPDATE :

I can't turn on the Bluetooth through the Charms menu -> Settings -> Change PC Settings -> Wireless. But I can turn on WiFi from there.

Also I searched in 'services.msc' and I was able to find 3 Bluetooth related services there out of which 2 were running.

Answer (score 0):

```
Things to check,

 Windows 7
     Press FN+F5 on your keyboard and make sure the Bluetooth status is ON.

 Windows 8
     Pull up the Charms bar

     Select the Settings charm, and then click Change PC settings.

     Select Wireless.

     You can now change the Bluetooth setting to On or Off.


 Check your mouse about paring mode or connect button underneath, (Some mouse has a trigger to pair)
Make sure that the Bluetooth services are started

       Press Windows button +R

               Type services.msc

                    Look for any Bluetooth related services and make sure they are on automatic and running.(system reboot needed after changes)



You can follow the guide on these articles
```

[Windows 8](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-add-a-bluetooth-gadget-to-a-windows-8-pc.html)

[Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952818)

[Source](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/G500-Bluetooth/td-p/1212846)

Comment: I looked in the services.msc and 3 bluetooth related services were there, out of which 2 were running. I can't turn on bluetooth through the charms menu.

Comment: @TominJacob Have you fixed the issue? I have the exact same problem, where there is no button to turn on the bluetooth, but the driver is correctly installed and all services are on.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 No. I can't fix the issue.

Comment: @TominJacob After some research I finally fixed it. Windows incorrectly installed a wrong driver for the Bluetooth receiver and that's why it's not working. After uninstalling the driver _completely_ and reinstalling the one that's on my recovery drive it is working fine now.